# Infinite loop happening somewhere here?

Tags: c++, loops, infinite-loop, primes

I'm writing a program to estimate the percentage of non-negative integers that are prime. The following code somehow produces an infinite loop, as my output is saying "Timeout" on the online compiler I'm using. However, I can't figure out what part of the code is producing the issue. It looks pretty straight-forward to me.

```
#include <iostream> 

bool isPrime(unsigned long L) { 
    if (L < 3) { 
        return true; 
    } else { 
        unsigned long i = 2;
        while (i < L)
           if (L % i++ == 0)
                return false;
    }
    return true;
}

int main() { 

    unsigned long k = 0;
    unsigned long N = ~k;
    unsigned long count = 0;
    while (k++ < N)  
        if (isPrime(k)) 
            ++count;

    long double percentPrime = count / N;
    std::cout << "Percentage of prime numbers from 0 to " << N << " = " << percentPrime;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Or it's running very slowly...

Comment: `if (L < 3) return true;` – That’s a rather daring redefinition of the term “prime”, you know …

Comment: There's no infinite loop. Just one very `long` one.

Comment: This does not appear to be infinite, as it will run until it reaches `0xffffffff`, but it is inefficient and will take forever.

Comment: Put some debug indfo at `while (i < L)`!

Comment: Funny definition of "estimate"...

Comment: your algorithm for finding prime numbers is the worst possible - computation wise; maybe you should rephrase the question and get some help optimizing your approach

Comment: Be aware that even if your computation somehow did run long enough to complete, `count / N;` results in `0`, because it performs integer division. That is one heck of a debugging cycle.

Comment: Then again, `0` *is* the percentage of non-negative integers that are prime (that is to say, it is the limit as M tends to infinity of the proportion of non-negative integers less than M that are prime). So just get rid of the loop and you're done ;-)

Comment: Finding all prime numbers below some limit is a bad way to estimate the frequency with which primes occur among positive integers - their density decreases as numbers grow larger.

Answer (score 2):

First off, your loop is not infinite.  It will run until it reaches `0xFFFFFFFF`, which will take forever.

Part of the reason it will take forever is you are using what amounts to an `O(N^2)` algorithm (so it will take `0xFFFFFFFF * 0xFFFFFFFF` operations to finish).

You should use a sieve, or at the very least, optimize your `is_prime` function:

```
bool is_prime(unsigned int i, const std::deque<unsigned int>& previous_primes)
{
    std::size_t j = 0;
    while (previous_primes[j] * previous_primes[j] <= i)
    {
        if (i % previous_primes[j] == 0)
            return false;
        ++j;
    }
    return true;
}
```

And your main code would then be:

```
// initialize some known primes
std::deque<unsigned int> primes;
primes.push_back(2);
primes.push_back(3);
primes.push_back(5);
primes.push_back(7);

for (unsigned int i = 9; i <= 0xFFFFFFFF; i += 2)
{
    if (is_prime(i, primes))
    {
        primes.push_back(i);
    }
}

// your percentage of primes would be (mathematically) primes.size() / 0xFFFFFFFF
```

Note that because of the iterations, this will *still* take forever to loop through all odd integers from 9 to 0xFFFFFFFF.

**Side Note**

Effectively, you are writing a program to show the following simple proof:

- Start with 2, so the percentage of primes must be less than .5, as every other number is divisible by 2.
- Next, 3, so the percentage of primes must be less than .33 as every 3rd number is divisible by 3.
- Next 5 ...

As the primes get larger and larger, the maximum percentage becomes `1/some infinite prime` ~= 0. (the limit of `f(x) = 1/x` as x approaches infinity is 0).

So here, the mathematical proof is much faster than your attempt at a programmatic proof.

Answer (score 1):

```
unsigned long k = 0;
unsigned long N = ~k;
```

Here N will be `0xFFFFFFFF` which is a really big number so the loop is not infinite but long.

Comment: Or `0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF` on 64 bit Linux systems.

Comment: Right, I tend to forgot about the different length on 64 bits since I always typedef them in my code.

Answer (score 1):

Not infinite, just extremely long.

It would have been infinite if you had written `while (k++ <= N)` instead of `while (k++ < N)`...

BTW, 1 is generally not considered a prime number, but your code yields that it is.

P.S.: If you want a rough estimation of the percentage of primes in the range `1...N`, then you can simply do the following math instead: `100/log(N)`, where `log(N)` is the natural logarithm of `N`.

Comment: Just a note:  the `100/log(N)` approximation comes from the [Prime Number Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem)

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't seems to be infinite, but since it is very long and time consuming it is timingout.

What I suggest is to improve your primality test with some tricks:

1 - you only need to test the number until its square root (sqrt(L))

2 - you only need to test odd numbers for primality (so you can start to try to divide the number by 3 and increase the test by 2, so you will test against 3,5,7,9,etc...)

Cheers

Comment: 3 - you only need to test against other prime numbers found earlier

Comment: @paul23 that is true, I didn't added this because you have to store the other primes somewhere and most of the time that is not reasonable. But you are correct, thanks for the reminder.

Comment: @prmottajr it sure *is* reasonable if you test more than just a few primes in a sequence. :)